# Problemm using concat in array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

i have 3 tables

```
1) Actor: actor_id, first_name, last_name 
2) Film: film_id, title
3) Film_Actor: film_id, actor_id
```

**Example document:**

```
_id
:
60aedac769985522a024daca
actor_id
:
"1"
first_name
:
"Penelope"
last_name
:
"Guiness"
```

I wanto to result not only first_name, but last_name too. I'm facing problem with using `concat` in `$group` function.
my FULLY codes:

```
    db.film.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "film_actor",
      localField: "film_id",
      foreignField: "film_id",
      as: "film_actor"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "actor",
      localField: "film_actor.actor_id", 
      foreignField: "actor_id",
      as: "actor"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$film_id",
      title: {"$first":"$title"},
      name: {$push: "$actor.first_name"}
                }
  }
]);
```

Error report:

```
$concat only supports strings, not array
```

**desired output:**

```
id:"207"
title:"Dangerous Uptown"
name:Array
0:"Penelope Guiness"
1:"Mary Watson"
2:"Ralph Holts"
3:"Spencer Dani"
```

Comment: post example document that you have in collection.

Comment: can you show us how your sample data looks?

Comment: @turivishal done, i have edit the question

Comment: @varman  done, i have edit the question

Comment: please post valid json format document, and I can not see `film_id` field in you document and you have used in $group.

Comment: What is your output before you grouping?

Comment: I think you don't understand us. We can't always waste the time to construct your sample documents. You need to give us the correct sample documents and what you tried in the code

Comment: @varman is it still unclear? i think i declare it clearly

Comment: @HerlambangPermadi No, this is not what we expecting. When you post a question, it should be clear enough. You have posted the format of the collections, not documents. SO we need to construct your document to answer, this will waste the time. And we need what you tried and what is the problem you faced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is appreciated, I've done some changes in your code

- `$lookup` to join collections. I have started form Flim collection
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to reconstruct the array that we already deconstructed, this will
- Since we have nested array we need to use `$map` to loop over them to collect the first name and lastname
- The above stage will end up with again nested array, so we use `$reduce` to loop again and remove inner arrays using `$setUnion`

remove some duplicate entries, depends on your requirements

Here is the code

```
db.Film.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Film_Actor",
      localField: "film_id",
      foreignField: "film_id",
      as: "join_flim"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$join_flim" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Actor",
      localField: "join_flim.actor_id",
      foreignField: "actor_id",
      as: "join_flim.join_actor"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      title: { $first: "$title" },
      join_flim: { $push: "$join_flim" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      title: 1,
      actornames: {
        $map: {
          input: "$join_flim",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $map: {
              input: "$$f.join_actor",
              as: "a",
              in: {
                $concat: [ "$$a.first_name", " ", "$$a.last_name" ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      title: 1,
      actornames: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$actornames",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$setUnion": [ "$$this", "$$value" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JsXtRCdzngp)**

Comment: thanks for your explanation. now i'm trouble facing with $unwind. my codes: `{ $unwind: "$join_flim"}` still reporting: unrecognized option to $unwind stage: $unwind
How to fix this? tahnks